# Fluent NHibernate one-to-many relationship setting foreign key to null

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a simple Fluent NHibernate model with two related classes:

```
public class Applicant
    {
        public Applicant()
        {
            Tags = new List<Tag>();
        }

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        //other fields removed for sake of example

        public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; protected set; }

        public virtual void AddTag(Tag tag)
        {
            tag.Applicant = this;
            Tags.Add(tag);
        }
    }


public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string TagName { get; set; }

    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
}
```

My fluent mapping is the following:

```
public class ApplicantMap : ClassMap<Applicant>
    {
        public ApplicantMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);

            HasMany(x => x.Tags).Cascade.All();
        }
    }

    public class TagMap : ClassMap<Tag>
    {
        public TagMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.TagName);

            References(x => x.Applicant).Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try to **update** an applicant (inserting a new one works fine), it fails and I see the following SQL exception in the logs:

```
11:50:52.695 [6] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - UPDATE [Tag] SET Applicant_id = null WHERE Applicant_id = @p0;@p0 = 37 [Type: Int32 (0)] 
11:50:52.699 [6] ERROR NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Could not execute command: UPDATE [Tag] SET Applicant_id = null WHERE Applicant_id = @p0 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Applicant_id', table 'RecruitmentApp.dbo.Tag'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

Why is NHibernate trying to update the tag table and set Applicant_id to null? I'm at a loss on this one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `Applicant.Tags` to `Inverse` will instruct NHibernate to save `Tags` after the `Applicant`.

```
public class ApplicantMap : ClassMap<Applicant>
{
    public ApplicantMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.Tags).Cascade.All().Inverse();
    }
}
```

More detail:

`Inverse` (as opposed to `.Not.Inverse()`) means the other side of the relationship (in this case, each `Tag`) is responsible for maintaining the relationship. Therefore, NHibernate knows that the `Applicant` must be saved first so that `Tag` has a valid foreign key for its `Applicant`.

Rule of thumb: The entity containing the foreign key is usually the owner, so the other table should have `Inverse`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! I'm still a little confused on what inverse means, but I'll do a little reading. I don't see it in the documentation though.

Comment: Thanks alot for resolving the issue it worked without any issues.

Comment: This is weird to me. Why is the tag the owner? The tags are tied to a specific Applicant. You create an applicant, then add tags to it. You don't create the tags, and associate them to an applicant?