# Fluent nhibernate One-to-Many when Inverse is used Child table's Foreign key is null

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many

I have a parent and child table and entites are created and mapped using one to many relation ship. On one to many side when i use Inverse() then the child table's foreign key value is inserted as null.

```
public class TableA
{
   public virtual long ID { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
   public virtual long ID { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
}

public class TableAMap : ClassMap<TableA>
{
   public TableAMap()
   {
      Id(x=>x.ID);
      Map(x=>x.Name).Column("Name");
      HasMany(x=>x.TableB)
          .KeyColumn("TableA_ID")
          .Inverse()
          .Cascase.All()
          .Not.LazyLoad();
   }
}

public class TableBMap : ClassMap<TableB>
{
   public TableBMap()
   {
      Id(x=>x.ID);
      Map(x=>x.Name).Column("Name");
      References(x=>x.TableA).Column("TableA_ID").Not.LazyLoad();
   }
}
```

**Note** When the `Inverse()` is removed from many to one the new records are inserted without any issues and the foreign key is inserted without any issues but when i update a record the foreign key of the existing records are replaced as null.

Please help me i looked in to similar questions but it doesn't help me.

[Fluent NHibernate one-to-many relationship setting foreign key to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213274/fluent-nhibernate-one-to-many-relationship-setting-foreign-key-to-null)

Comment: You should post your real mapping. Your `HasMany<TableA>(x=>x.TableB).KeyColumn("TableA_ID").Inverse().Cascase.All().Not.LazyLoad();` doesn't seem to work with `<TableA>`

Comment: Yes sorry i have corrected the one with `HasMany<TableB>(x=>x.TableB).KeyColumn("TableA_ID").Inverse().Cascase.All().Not‌​.LazyLoad();`

Comment: This example is hard to decipher. Again, I think you should post the actual code (or a subset of it) and also the schema you're currently working with.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this link which has the solution for this issue.

[Refer this Solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213517/559227)

The map class should be:

```
public class TableAMap : ClassMap<TableA>
{
   public TableAMap()
   {
      Id(x=>x.ID);
      Map(x=>x.Name).Column("Name");
      HasMany<TableB>(x=>x.TableB)
          .KeyColumn("TableA_ID")
          .Cascade.All().Inverse();
   }
}

public class TableBMap : ClassMap<TableB>
{
   public TableBMap()
   {
      Id(x=>x.ID);
      Map(x=>x.Name).Column("Name");
      References<TableA>(x=>x.TableA).Column("TableA_ID").Not.Nullable();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to tell exactly without seeing the code which inserts. However my crystal ball tells me you probably forgot the last line

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child();
parent.Children.Add(child);
child.Parent = parent;     <-- this is important because this will maintain the foreign key
```